# AngularJS promise and Local variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm adding a component to an existing system. Most of the time, this component will deal with one item but there's a request to support multiple items. For example, visualizing certain item in a graph and if multiple items are selected, all will be included in the same graph.

They have a service to get a specific item, or all items but not selective items.

I have something like this

```js
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
          var item = $scope.items[i];
          if (item.isSelected) {
            $scope.selectedItems[item.name] = { 
                /* certain initial properties are set here */ 
                nesteItems: []
            };
            thierService.getItem(item.id)
              .then(function(data) {
                // here I want to have access to item.name to reset the properties with correct values, 
                // for example:
                $scope.selectedItems[item.name].nesteItems = data.nestedItems;

              })
          }
        }
```

Is there a way using promise to do this? or has to work around it with closure?

Comment: You already are using a promise. Can you clarify what you expect to be different in your desired result?

Comment: item.name inside the promise is getting invalid value as item was defined outside the callback scope.

Comment: You have the typical problem when using functions in a for-loop. The `then` will see only the `item` of the last loop iteration, not that of `items[i]`.

Comment: Currently to workaround this, I have something like var handler = function(name) {return function(data, status) {} } and pass it like ....then(handler(item.name))

Comment: I am asking if there's a better way to handle this?

Comment: @AnasMosaad: No, [using a closure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) is totally the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's convenient to join `thierService.getItem` call for all selected items to one promise and handle result.

```
var selectedItemsNames = [], promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    var item = $scope.items[i];
    if(item.isSelected) {
        selectedItemsNames.push(item.name);
        promises.push(thierService.getItem(item.id));
    }
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.selectedItems[selectedItemsNames[i]] = { nesteItems: data[i].nestedItems };
    };
});
```